# Using POST array to select elements in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I am trying to create a `$mysqli->prepare` statement where instead of using the `POST` values I have as values, I want to use them to select the elements I am updating.  The array comes from a set of multiple select html items on the prior page.

```
foreach($_POST['times'] as $val){

    if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stud_sched SET ? ='a' WHERE s_id = (?)"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!($stmt->bind_param("sd",$val, $pid))){
        echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }
        $stmt->close();
}
```

However, I am getting the following:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /nfs/stak/students/s/searsjo/public_html/student_added.php on line 107 (the bind statement)
>
> Prepare failed: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /nfs/stak/students/s/searsjo/public_html/student_added.php on line 109

This seems like something I should be able to do, but I cannot find any information regarding it.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot bind field names, over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/pdo.prepare.php) does not state that one can bind column names to variables/values. According to an [interesing comment](http://php.net/manual/ro/pdo.prepare.php#111977) it is recommended to white list the permitted column names in your query using `in_array` for example. So your code could look similar to this:

```
foreach($_POST['times'] as $column){

    if(!in_array($column, array('someColumn', 'someOtherColumn', 'yetAnotherColumn')))
    {
        die("Column not permitted in query");
    }

    if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE stud_sched SET $column ='a' WHERE s_id = (?)"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!($stmt->bind_param("s",$pid))){
        echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to help :)